# Live site still taking nodes url as localhost/

Tags: nodes, uri

I have developed a Drupal site on localhost; I then exported it to a production site, and made the required changes in settings.php.
The index page opens fine, but when I log in, the URL is still referring to localhost.
I tried to set the base URL in settings.php, but it did not help.

I am using Drupal 7.10.

Comment: Did you modify the .htaccess file previously?

Comment: nopes i did not do any modifications in .htaccess, but you could tell me what are the settings that i should look for in .htaccess i can double check that

Comment: Are you using the domain module? securepages module?

Comment: No i am not using any such module.I dont know from where it is taking localhost/ path for user log in

Comment: ok, i found it, There were lot of cache tables with values localhost/.....  although i ahd already cleared cache under performance, but seems these values left so had to manually delete them

Comment: @RakeshJuneja, Where did you find those cache tables with values localhost/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clearing all Drupal caches at yourwebsite.domain/admin/config/development/performance

Comment: ok, as per your advise i cleared cache under Performance, but still the same.

Comment: @RakeshJuneja Did you solve the issue? can you please add your answer..

Comment: @RakeshJuneja cleared the cache but didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Try to clear all entries in table cache_page

Comment: cleared all the entries in table 'cache_page'. Also used Devel module to clear cache. but same problem. Do we need to edit .htaccess file @RakeshJuneja

Comment: You can see my post [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/137582/urls-getting-duplicated-for-the-same-node)