# URLs getting duplicated for the same node

Tags: nodes, theming, uri

Yesterday, I found a strange behavior with my drupal site. I noticed all the nodes are getting duplicated like this:

**Original node's url will be**

> www.livesite.org/?q=node/2

And when I append the url with the **somerandom** name like this

> www.livesite.org/**randomname**/?q=node/2

The same page gets displayed but with broken images and logos.

I'm sure there might with the my template's `template.php` file, but I'm not sure what to edit. Does anyone came across this issue?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by adding the /randomname path component? How are people going to be getting to this URL exactly (other than by typing it in manually?). There's two ways Drupal urls work - you either do rewriting properly, or you don't do it at all...

Comment: The good thing is people can't get into /randomname. But somehow I got into it and wanted to get rid of this any idea?? @murraybiscuit

Comment: This behaviour is probably to allow for Drupal installs in a subdirectory, without clean urls enabled. In which case you'd probably need to statically set the site root in your settings.php file so that linked assets get prepended with the webroot prefix. Which probably isn't your use case. Changing this behaviour would require fiddling with your rewrite rules, which may get overridden by future core updates, so not advised.